# Data Fatch with React (Nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, nsfetchrequest, urlfetch

I'm using the next.js and i'm doing the fetch data fetch from json. Now i can't see the data from json (that change when i refresh) for example in the first box of the table.

Can someone help me? I just tried for so many days and i can't resolve.

```js
import styles from '../styles2/Tabelle.module.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Fetch() {
    'use client';
    const [appState, setAppState] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('https://run.mocky.io/v3/f3bf41f3-c60a-47f8-9386-243989bead65');
            const json = await response.json();
            setAppState(json);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const date = (
        <ul>
            {appState.map((item) => (
                <li key={item.id}> {item.id} </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID ESECUZIONE </th> <th>NOME PROCESSO</th> <th>HOST</th> <th>ANDAMENTO</th> <th>DURATA</th> <th>AVANZAMENTO</th>{' '}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr className={styles.righeEsecuzioni}>
                        <td> {date.key} </td>{' '}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: did you check you Get URL is sending response
It's say cors error , Means you don't have permission to get response

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the response string does not contain array paranthesis [ ] in start and end thats why parsing JSON causing error

use axios library and you can do it like this

import library

```
 import axios from 'axios';
```

fetch data

```
 const response = await axios.get(
    'https://run.mocky.io/v3/f3bf41f3-c60a-47f8-9386-243989bead65'
  );
```

now add parenthesis at start and end

```
 const string = '[' + response.data + ']';
```

now setState

```
setAppState(JSON.parse(string));
```

Overall code looks like this

```
 import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Fetch() {
  'use client';
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(
        'https://run.mocky.io/v3/f3bf41f3-c60a-47f8-9386-243989bead65'
      );
      const string = '[' + response.data + ']';
      setAppState(JSON.parse(string));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  const date = (
    <ul>
      {appState.map((item: any) => (
        <li key={item.id}> {item.id} </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID ESECUZIONE </th> <th>NOME PROCESSO</th> <th>HOST</th>{' '}
            <th>ANDAMENTO</th> <th>DURATA</th> <th>AVANZAMENTO</th>{' '}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td> {date} </td>{' '}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sort by Date

Using dayjs library

Add this after string variable

```
const response = await axios.get(
    'https://run.mocky.io/v3/f3bf41f3-c60a-47f8-9386-243989bead65'
  );
  const string = '[' + response.data + ']';
  const parsedString = JSON.parse(string);
  parsedString.sort((date1: any, date2: any) => {
    return dayjs(date1.Giorno).isBefore(dayjs(date2.Giorno)) ? -1 : 1;
  });
  setAppState(parsedString);
```

Comment: Amazing it's work but i have a list now like this (ID ESECUZIONE:  8Bryce88
3Deontae16
5Jarrod23
7Jaydon86
7Manley17
3Bertha47
6Minerva25
1Vicenta26
0Anita31
4Julius58
...)    How can i have just one "ID" random inside the box table?

Comment: You can use Math.random() for random index of array and then display that index id

Comment: I dont understand your 2nd question ?

Comment: I resolved the second question thank you so much :)

Comment: what about  if  i have to order all the data and show in the table in chronological order? (i have the the attribute"giorno" that show me the data in my json)

Comment: How the code will change?

Comment: I think the data is already in chronological order by date. You can use Javascript built in  sort method to sort it by date

Comment: In which part of the code? Bc doesn't work

Comment: Have you resolved it ? Sorry I was busy.

Comment: Not yet. Do u can help me?

Comment: I added code in my answer above.